# downloading error file more than 10 MB

Tags: downloading

I am using symphony w 10,there is enough space in my memory card but  I can not download file size more than 10 mb. There is no space left in phone storage.

Answer (score 1):

The phone stores the downloads in the internal memory by default. You could do the following,

- Delete unwanted apps. Clear your cache.
- Move [apps to SD card](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ljmobile.move.app)
- Change the default location of your camera to SD card.